# A classic analog to rotating wave approximation

Tags: classical-mechanics, quantum-optics

I am looking for a realistic example of the analog of Rotating Wave Approximation in classical systems.
I understand the basic idea of the approximation, and I applied it to a simple second-order differential equation:
$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-25x(t)+\cos[\Omega t+x'(t)]$$
When I calculate numericaly the solution of this equation, increasing the value of $\Omega$, I found succesfully that the solution approximates to the harmonic oscillator solution, but I would like to have a relistic physic model, for example a pendulum in an external electric field. I have tried to contruct  a such model, but I have failed because I never achieve to have a sinusoidal force acting over the particle that depends, not only of the time, also of the position or the velocity. Can anybody help me?